# One to Many and a Many to Many relationship Entity Framework including default Authorization and role managing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a system that produce some online classes. In this class we have students and a teacher.
I have used Microsoft default `Identity System and Authorization` for this system, but something is bothering me in my design.

For more explanation I want to define Roles(Teacher, Students, Admins and etc) , but it is so confusing how to handle relation between Course and Teacher (it is one to many relation) and Course to Students (it has many to many relation).

So I have question is that true way to have two relation between two entities or not? if it is not, How should I handle this?

Here is my Course entity

```
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "شناسه")]
        public Guid CourseId { get; set; }       

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "لوگوی دوره")]
        public string LogoPath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "نام دوره")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "شرح دوره")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "شهریه")]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "دارای تخفیف")]
        public bool HasDiscount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "درصد تخفیف")]
        public float DiscountPercentage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "آخرین تاریخ به روزرسانی")]
        public DateTime LastUpdateUpdate { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public AppUser CourseTeacher { get; set; }

        public Guid CaptionId { get; set; }

        public MainCaption CourseCaption{ get; set; }

        public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AppUser> Students{ get; set; }
```

and here is my AppUser entity

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "نام")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "نام خانوادگی")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "جنسیت")]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "عنوان")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "اعتبار")]
        public int Credit { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تاریخ تولد")]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "مدرک تحصیلی")]
        public EducationalDegree? Degree { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس تصویر")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تصویر تایید شده")]
        public bool? IsImageConfirmed { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس فیس بوک")]
        public string Facebook { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس اینستاگرام")]
        public string Instagram { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس لینکداین")]
        public string Linkedin { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس توئیتر")]
        public string Twitter { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "آدرس وبسایت")]
        public string Website { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تاریخ ثبت نام")]
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Course> StudentCourses { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Course> TeacherCourses { get; set; }

        public ICollection<News> WrittenNews { get; set; }
```

Tnx to All

**Edit**

I forgot to say this contains an error `Sequence contains more than one matching element` and it seems logical

One important this is that if I use same class for inheritance how should I add two relations for this two tables AppUser and Course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define Roles(Teacher, Students, Admins and etc)

You can do it in a couple different ways:

- Have `User` and `Role` tables and enforce roles on the application level, e.g. Only "teacher" user can do teacher things, only student can enrol into courses etc.
- With EF you can use inheritance. Abstract `User` would have all the common fields and Student, Teacher and Admin would have fields specific only to their role.

Please see the code:

```
abstract class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Teacher : User
{
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
}

class Student : User
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - the example given in this official documentation is very close to what you're trying to achieve.

> Course to Students (it has many to many relation)

For this type of a relationship I'd create a new table/entity StudentCourse with composite (StudentId, CourseId) key. And the reason for it is, usually you don't just want a link between 2 entities but also to keep some additional info like `Mark`, `Performance` or `EnrolmentDate`:

```
class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    // Any additional fields related to the relationship
    public int Mark { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. In this way Is Authorization and role managing working for both? Some Of my functions are for teachers and the other are for students

Comment: @BehzadHassani well auth is a different question, I'd handle it by separating student related controllers from teacher and admin controllers and implement different policies for different roles.

Comment: I have mentioned Identity system in first paragraph of my question. Of course default identity system has authorization and role managing too. but tnx for response.

Comment: @BehzadHassani yes you'd need to work on customizing your identity system by adding policies for different roles and applying those policies to your controllers. If I be your, I'd work on the db schema first, and then once I'm comfortable with it, I'd look into auth. Auth itself is a pretty long story.

Comment: I have read your example and your self written code and I am agree with both. My dbschema had some faults and you change my mind because with this design authentication will come easy. Upvote. Tnx many times.